# Routing error for GET] "/firstapp"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-routing

I was trying to write my first program after installation, but I got an error like below:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/firstapp"
```

I've tried to change my `config/routes.rb` file but nothing changed. This is my `config/routes.rb`

```
Firstapp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :apptables

  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # continues with default `config/routes.rb` explanations...
end
```

How can I configure the `config/routes.rb` to make it run properly?

Comment: how about removing all the comments in the file `routes.rb`?

Comment: You don't need to add the `/firstapp` in your url. Just visiting `http://localhost:3000/` should suffice. This will result in another error, though, because you haven't defined a `root` route.

Answer (score 3):

Just saying `resources :apptables` [sets up the standard seven routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions):

```
GET    /apptables
GET    /apptables/new
POST   /apptables
GET    /apptables/:id
GET    /apptables/:id/edit
PUT    /apptables/:id
DELETE /apptables/:id
```

There is no `/firstapp` in that list so that route won't work. If you want a GET on `/firstapp` to work then you can set up that route manually:

```
match '/firstapp' => 'firstapp#some_method', :via => :get
```

That would route GET `/firstapp` to `FirstappController#some_method`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any difference between your `match ... :via => :get` route and `get '/firstapp' => 'firstapp#some_method'` ?

Comment: @Adam: I don't think so, just a matter of habit and preference. The guide I linked to should have more on that though.